AttributeError: 'Pathway' object has no attribute 'hidden'
I am attempting to create a nested dictionary 'world'. Due to the planned size and complexity I am hoping to automate the creation a bit. However, when I attempt to run it, I get "AttributeError: 'Pathway' object has no attribute 'hidden'". The intended structure of the dictionary is as follows
**world

village
a. rooms
i. villageEntrance
1. hidden : false
2. pathways: [p1,etc]
ii. etc
b. alignment : good
c. etc
void
a. rooms
i. voidRoom
1. hidden : false
2. pathways: [p1]
b. alignment : neutral
c. etc**

class Pathway(dict):
    def __init__(self, hidden, travelType):
        self.dict = {
            self.hidden : hidden,
            self.travelType : travelType
        }

class Room(dict):
    def __init__(self, hidden, pathways):
        self.dict = {
            self.hidden : hidden,
            self.pathways : pathways
        }

class Location(dict):
   def __init__(self, rooms, alignment):
      self.dict = {
          self.alignment : alignment,
          self.rooms : rooms
      }

p1 = Pathway(True, "teleport")

voidRoom = Room(True, [p1])
villageEntrance = Room(False, [p1])

void = Location([voidRoom], "neutral")
village = Location([villageEntrance], "good")

world = {
    "void" : void,
    "village" : village
}

def locationDataRetrieval(path):
    val = world.get(path)
    return val

print(world)

I looked up proper syntax for dictionaries and as far as I can see I have it correct. I also attempted removing the pathway class but the error moved on to the next class.

Do you really want to store things in a sub-dictionary?  I would think a direct attribute such as p1.hidden would be simpler and cleaner.

The way this is written, the attribute would be something like p1.dict['hidden'].  Did you really want that?

And what is the purpose of making these a subclass of dict?

This is python, not javascript.
class Pathway(dict):
    def __init__(self, hidden, travelType):
        self.dict = {
            self.hidden : hidden,
            self.travelType : travelType
        }

PEP 8
asks you to instead name it travel_type.
It's not strictly necessary to define all attributes in
the __init__() constructor, but it's good practice, it's considered polite.
Here, you're attempting to dereference self.hidden before
you have assigned anything to it.
A typical ctor would look like:
    def __init__(self, hidden, travel_type):
        self.hidden = hidden
        self.travel_type = travel_type

After that it's perfectly fine to dereference self.hidden.
You can even put it in a dict if you like.
It's unclear why that would be desirable, though.
I recommend you settle on object attributes, or settle on dicts,
without trying to mix them.
Storing the same thing in two places tends to lead to maintenance trouble
later on.

A @dataclass
decorator can save you the trouble of writing a ctor:
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Pathway:
    hidden: bool
    travel_type: str


my bad ive been taking a javascript class and getting methods mixed up. Overall makes sense, thanks for your help!
